# How to disable left menu in master detail page in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have masterdetail page and there is left menu in it. Its working fine during user is on masterdetail page. But When user move from master detail page to simple content page(that is not part of master detail page), on this content page if he swipe from left to right left menu opens. 
How I can disable the left menu on this content page? and why left menu is showing on simple content page while it is not part of the master detail page?

Answer (score 6):

If you're still looking for a solution, you can do it like so:

```
IsGestureEnabled = false;
```

You can continue to use

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new PageWhichWontOpenTheMenu());
```

To use it, simply get the RootPage (the MasterDetailPage) on the OnAppearing method like so:

```
protected override void OnAppearing(){
        base.OnAppearing();
        (Application.Current.MainPage as RootPage).IsGestureEnabled = false;
}
```

Tell me if it works for you, cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You can only disable the gesture from master details page.

It can be solve by notifying that the current page is not master page:

1)When we are setting the Master details page by

```
 Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page));
 IsGestureEnabled = true;// always set it true when setting a page to master page
```

2)Use MessagingCenter from MasterDetails Page for notifying that the current page is not a master page:(inside the master page constructor)

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string>(this, "DisableGesture", (sender) =>
            {
                if(sender == "0")
                {
                    IsGestureEnabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    IsGestureEnabled = true;
                }
            });
```

3)when you navigate from a nornal content page,and you dont want to open the master menu from here then notify the master page IsGestureEnabled = false;

```
//content page OnAppearing method
 protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send<string>("0", "DisableGesture");
        }
```

do this for all your content page,where you dont want to open master menu.
****and remember that which pages you are setting as master page,for those pages onappearing method send messaging center with value "1"

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send<string>("1", "DisableGesture");
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Better yet what you can do in your `OnMenuItemSelected` event for your SideMenu list is check for the type that you want to Disable the SideMenu for and then set IsGestureEnabled to false when navigating to that page:

```
private void OnMenuItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = (SideMenuItem)e.SelectedItem;
            var page = item.TargetType;
            if (page == typeof(PageToDisableMenu))
                IsGestureEnabled = false;
            Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page));
            IsPresented = false;
        }
```

I know this answer is late but I hope it helps someone in the future :).

Answer (score 0):

You probably use `Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(...)` instead of that use `Navigation.PushAsync(...)`

Comment: That doesn't work, when swipe from left, the menu still appears. To really disable, I found one way, use Navigation.`PushModalAsync(...)`

Answer (score 0):

To really disable, I found one way, use Navigation.`PushModalAsync(...)`. But this way, you don't have the navigation bar at the top anymore. You can build one yourself though.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for was to disable the whole MasterDetailPage with the **IsEnabled** property.

In may case executing a process from an option menu (not navigation or change the Detail page) and I needed to block any interaction of the user with the page.

Hope this helps.

Regards